# How to create use Draw methods from a class onto a JPanel in another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

I have 2 classes, one class is my GUI frameviewer. The other is a class that I am trying to use with my project. The class LabeledBar provides a draw method. I will have an ArrayList of the LabeledBars in my FrameViewer class. I want to iterate through that list and create a new Panel holding these bars. I can't quite figure out how to draw these bars onto that frame.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
/** LabeledBar is a rectangle with an interior label.
 * 
 *
 */
public class LabeledBar
{
    private int xLeft;
    private int yTop;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private String label;
    private Color color;
    /** Construct this object from the specified dimensions.
     * @param x x coordinate of the upper-left corner of this bar.
     * @param y y coordinate of the upper-left corner of this bar.
     * @param aWidth width of the bar in pixels.
     * @param label the text to be displayed inside the bar.
     * @param color desired color of the lines of the bar.
     */
    public LabeledBar(int x, int y, int aWidth, String label, Color color)
    {
        xLeft = x;
        yTop = y;
        width = aWidth;
        height = 20;
        this.label = label;
        this.color = color;
    }

    /** Draw this bar on the supplied graphics context.
     * @param g2 the context on which to draw this bar.
     */
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
    {
        Rectangle leftRectangle = new Rectangle(
            xLeft, yTop,
            width, height);

        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.draw(leftRectangle);
        g2.drawString(label, xLeft+height/4, yTop+height*3/4);
    }
}
```

This is my a method from my other class in attempt to create a new JFrame that includes the labeledBars in them.

```
 private void paintBars()
{
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)labeledBarsFrame.getGraphics();

    for (LabeledBar element: bars)
    {
        element.draw(g);
    }
    //labeledBarsFrame.add(g);
}
```

Comment: Look up M-V-C or Model-View-Controller, and structure your program in this fashion. Never draw using a Graphics object obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a component. Instead draw within a JPanel's paintComponent method. Read the Swing Graphics tutorial since guessing at this stuff is a bad way to learn how to do it. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: You don't delete the text of your question when the problem is solved. You "accept" the answer that helped solve the problem so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Question text rolled back. Swager, please do not deface your question. This site is not a personal help site but a question/answer site, where common questions and there answers are posted for all to see and for all to gain from. By defacing your question, you make it completely unhelpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to iterate through that list and create a new Panel holding these bars. I can't quite figure out how to draw these bars onto that frame.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

The `DrawOnComponent` examples should get you started in the right direction. It shows how to paint custom Objects found in an ArrayList.

Basically you need to create a `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent(...)` to iterate through your `ArrayList` and invoke the `draw(...)` method on each of your Objects. The panel is then added to the frame.